# how to request.getParameter() in case of dynamic selection list

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

i am working with jsp. i have a dynamic selection list. i want to request.getParameter(). how does it work for dynamic selection list? the code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function optionsChange(){   
        var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
        if(service == 'GSM'){   
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'block';
        }else if(service == 'CDMA'){
            document.getElementById("gsmService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'none';
        } 
    }
</script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
    <td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICE:</b></font> </td>
    <td><select id="service" name="service" onChange="javascript:optionsChange();">
            <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
            <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
        </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VAS :</b></font> </td></tr>
<tr id="gsmService">
    <td><select name="gsmService" > 
        <option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>
        <option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
        <option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
        </select>   
    </td>
</tr>   
<tr id="cdmaService">
    <td><select name="cdmaService" >
        <option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
        <option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
        <option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

since both the lists have different names "gsmservice" and "cdmaservice". but they are dynamic so only one of them appears at a time depending on the selection in the 1st selection list(GSM/CDMA). how can i use request.getParameter() to see what value has been selected. because if i use request.getParameter(gsm service), it returns only gsm services. if i use request.getParameter(cdmaservice ), it return only cdma services. 
how can it be done. any sugestions?

Comment: where do you use `request.getparameter()` here ? and where do you want you need to use it ?

Comment: i'm using it on the next page. lets say i just want to display the selection on the next page. how can we do it?

Comment: First be clear about `request.getparameter()` , it is used to display the request object as `String` . so it will display what you have selected in the firstPage on the second one

Comment: yes .. right.. 
`String service = request.getParameter("gsmService");`  returns only gsm services. 

`String service = request.getParameter("cdmaService");` returns only cdma services.

i need it to return which ever is selected dynamically

Comment: So the possibility is either of this two will be `null` always (i.e) only one will be present

Comment: yes.  but there has to be a way out of this.

Comment: Then why dont you verify `null` and print on your server side

Comment: As you have different select box you have to retrieve them separately alone . no other go!

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: okay, see. the thing is . this code is part of a welcome page where the user selects the service (GSM/CDMA) and then the dynamic selection list shows other choices accordingly. then the user is taken to another page where the user can see some details. these details are fetched from a database and the query which is run to get those details from the database, includes the selected choice. so if i retrieve them separately, i'll have two results and the query won't run. it has to return only one selection

Comment: i will add an answer , you try it

Comment: sure. thanks. i'll keep trying..!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might work , but this is a tricky solution..

Initially don't add name to your select box  as fields without name will not be validated in the request

```
       <select id="service"  onChange="javascript:optionsChange();">
            <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
            <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
        </select>
```

Then using javascrpt add the name to the select ,

```
if(service == 'GSM'){   
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'block';
            $('#select1ID').attr('name', 'services');
        }else if(service == 'CDMA'){
            document.getElementById("gsmService").value= '';
            document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'none';
            $('#select2ID').attr('name', 'services');
        }
```

And on the server side , you could get the value from `services` alone

**Update ::**

So the better way i would prefer is checking for `NUll` in the page after submit like below,

```
    String serviceType = "";
    serviceType = request.getParameter("service");
if(service.equals("gsm"))
{
//display this
}
else 
{
//display this 
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: i tried it. but this isn't working either. but i like the idea. i got the jist of what you are trying to do here. i'm trying. and please if you come out with any other solution do let me know.
Thanks in advance..!! :)

Comment: Check my update and let me know if you need any help